# Copying features from a shapefile into feature class using ArcPy with ArcMap gives ERROR 000725

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-000725

I have a shapefile which contains some features and I need to copy these features and paste them into an EXISTING feature class using ArcPy. I have tried the (`arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(..)`) but it seems it is used only to copy data from a shapefile to a NEW feature class.

```
import arcpy
input_ShapeFile ="C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\file.shp"
output_FeatureClass ="C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\Data.mdb\fc" 
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input_ShapeFile, output_FeatureClass)
```

```
...ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset "C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\Data.mdb\fc"
 already exists. Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

I think that both your paths need to be turned into raw strings:

```
input_ShapeFile = r"C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\file.shp"
output_FeatureClass = r"C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\Data.mdb\fc"
```

and, as [commented by @BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355265/copying-features-from-a-shapefile-into-feature-class-using-arcpy-with-arcmap-giv#comment581919_355265), try using [Append](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) (instead of Copy Features) which:

> Appends multiple input datasets into an existing target dataset. Input
>   datasets can be feature classes, tables, shapefiles, rasters,
>   annotation or dimensions feature classes.